# Looking for YA SciFi book series about boy who finds out he's an alien

Tags: story-identification, aliens, young-adult

Probably published in the 90s. I read it sometime in 2001-2003. The Main Character (male) has these recurring dreams in which mysterious people in lab coats are doing experiments on him. The dreams were actually memories - I think he ends up being an alien? It's a series, and the main focus from what I remember is him trying to figure out who/what he is and where he came from. He spent much of the time on the run I think? Either from government or maybe the lab coat people.

Comment: Hello and Welcome! It looks like you've got a few good details there. Unfortunately they look like they may show up quite frequently in various works, so take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details :)

Comment: I'm looking for the same book I believe. The Atrian Messenger. He meets an older alien who protects n trains him.

Comment: I have been unable to find *The Atrian Messenger*, so I'm skeptical.

Comment: Ironically it could just as easily be The Maze Runner, although that was published much to late and doesn't involve aliens

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[The Antrian Messenger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0525671749) by G. Clifton Wisler. It is indeed [part of a trilogy](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/bookseries/B00CJ0MUCK).

From a [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/814396.The_Antrian_Messenger) review:

> Scott's always been a pretty ordinary kid--so he thinks--but when
>   certain odd occurrences keep happening to him, he is left with tons of
>   questions. Why is he having premonitions, and what will he sacrifice
>   if he dedicates himself to stopping the disasters he's dreaming?
>   **Before long he uncovers the truth of his origin: he is not human, but
>   Antrian**, and an older and wiser companion named Tiaf is ready and
>   waiting to teach him about his heritage (and his prophetic abilities,
>   among other things). But he soon realizes he can't both fulfill his
>   destiny and live a normal life with his family, so he has to make the
>   hardest choice of his life--and once he chooses, he can't go back.

Comment: Just noting that, if ever accepted, this would probably be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9152/looking-for-two-stories-about-a-telekinetic-boy/16600#16600